# Why wordpress add inline CSS style to images automatically?

Tags: css, image, wordpress

I have placed images on wordpress page templates without any inline style attribute but its seem wordpress automatically add style tag with width and height set to zero.

```
<img src="wp-content/themes/ecoblog/images/hiw-image-1.png" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
```

Sometimes height is set to its original dimentsions and sometimes after complete refresh its values are zero.

What is causing this?

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not done by WordPress itself. It is done by a plugin or the theme. Try disableing plugins to see which one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is caused by incorrect CSS. Zero values should not have dimensions, like `px` or `pt`. Like this:

```
<img src="wp-content/themes/ecoblog/images/hiw-image-1.png" style="width:0; height:0;">
```

Comment: but I am not applying any style to images, wordpress automatically add style with width height set to zero!

Comment: Adding dimensions to 0 values should not matter in general, although not encouraged.

Comment: I am not adding any style. It gets inserted automatically to images. When I look in html, I find in style attribute in images tag.

Comment: Doing the following: 
```grep 'width: 0px;' `find .` 2>/dev/null```



I get:



```./wp-content/plugins/slimjetpack/modules/shortcodes/css/slideshow-shortcode.css:        width: 0px;```



```./wp-content/plugins/slimjetpack/modules/shortcodes/css/rtl/slideshow-shortcode-rtl.css:        width: 0px;```



So the Slim Jetpack plugin appears to be the culprit in my case.

Saying that, its in a css file, not PHP/JS so I wonder how it has any effect on the HTML output...

Answer (score 0):

this is because of template CSS styles are override your image style properties ..,the easy way is to wrap your image content and give div id and put your style code in template CCS file
inside(style.css)

Answer (score -1):

it works as:

```
.class{
  width:20px !important;
  height:20px !important;
}
```

or if you want to remove Inline CSS completely , This inline css may be in .php files or in.js files.

You can search style in whole project , it is easier to search if you are using netbeans code editor.
Hope it may resolve.

Comment: !important is bad practice so is inline css, so you should fix that problem, not fix it while makin git worse

Comment: @janw using !important is not bad practice when you have inline css but you dont know where inline css exists. ok

Comment: But you can alter it, since a plugin/theme does is.